# How do I clear my bindings in DHCP I have a bind error

Tags: dhcp, cobbler

Hi I am currently running cobbler and dhcp, it all worked before rebooting ubuntu now after I have restarted the main service I am getting this error in m syslog

/var/syslog ....

```
bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98))
. service = tftp
```

xinetd -d

```
17/5/21@17:42:25: ERROR: 3249 {activate_normal} bind failed (Permission denied (err
no = 13)). service = tftp
17/5/21@17:42:25: ERROR: 3249 {cnf_start_services} Service tftp failed to start and
 is deactivated.
17/5/21@17:42:25: DEBUG: 3249 {cnf_start_services} mask_max = 0, services_started =
 0
```

Please could you advise me on how I clear out the addresses

Thanks

Lewis

Comment: It seems to be due to the tftpd address is in use, although I have rebooted the ubuntu machine.

Comment: See which program has the port allocated:  `sudo lsof -i udp:tftp`

Comment: Hi @waltinator thank you, I have tried this and checked the port but I still have the original error. If I rebuild the machine and get it working, is there any way to preserve the state before I reboot it in the future?

Comment: DON'T REBUILD! It won't help. Fix this problem. What did `sudo lsof -i udp:tftp` show? It's an information-gathering step, not the fix.